# Getting error Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int32

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I am grouping data in datatable and summing up one column using linq but while run time i am getting error stating that

> Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int32. Please use a nullable type" Below is my code

```
Dim resultStyle = invData.Tables(0).AsEnumerable() _
      .GroupBy(Function(v) New With {Key .InvestorStyleID = v.Field(Of Integer)("InstitutionalInvestorStyleID"), Key .StyleName = Not IsNothing(v.Field(Of String)("InstitutionalInvestorStyleName"))}) _
      .Select(Function(v) New With {Key .InvestorStyleID = v.Key.InvestorStyleID, Key .StyleName = v.Key.StyleName, Key .Sum = v.Sum(Function(r) Double.Parse(r.Item("k001ICGeo").ToString()))})
```

Kindly suggest me how to avoid taking null value.I am getting error on second line

`.GroupBy(Function(v) New With {Key .InvestorStyleID = v.Field(Of Integer)("InstitutionalInvestorStyleID"), Key .StyleName = Not IsNothing(v.Field(Of String)("InstitutionalInvestorStyleName"))}).`

I don't want to take the null value.

Comment: I believe the problem is the InstitutionalInvestorStyleID. Check if this is nullable in database. Try `v.Field(Of Integer?)("InstitutionalInvestorStyleID")`

Answer (score 1):

DataTables do not store null values, instead, they store `DBNull`.

Your `IsNothing` is therefore not helpful.

So, you need to compare with `DBNull.Value` (a singleton of DBNull).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim resultStyle = invData.Tables(0).AsEnumerable() _
                        .GroupBy(Function(v) New With {Key .InvestorStyleID = v.Field(Of Integer?)("InstitutionalInvestorStyleID").GetValueOrDefault, 
                                                        Key .StyleName = If( String.IsNullOrEmpty(v.Field(Of String)("InstitutionalInvestorStyleName")),"", v.Field(Of String)("InstitutionalInvestorStyleName"))}) _
                        .Select(Function(v) New With {Key .InvestorStyleID = v.Key.InvestorStyleID, Key .StyleName = v.Key.StyleName, Key .Sum = v.Sum(Function(r) Convert.ToDouble(r.Item("k001ICGeo"))))})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am not getting any error now but i don't want to take that particular row if the stylename is null or "".How to avoid taking that row.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is because you have null values in column which you are trying to cast while grouping, so simply change it to `Nullable` type. Also, to get only the records which don't have null values apply a filter using `Where` clause like this:-

```
Dim resultStyle = invData.Tables(0).AsEnumerable() _
    .GroupBy(Function(v) New With {Key .InvestorStyleID = v.Field(Of Integer?)("InstitutionalInvestorStyleID"), Key .StyleName = Not IsNothing(v.Field(Of String)("InstitutionalInvestorStyleName"))}) _
    .Where(Function(x) x.Key.InvestorStyleID  IsNot Nothing) _
    .Select(Function(v) New With {Key .InvestorStyleID = v.Key.InvestorStyleID, Key .StyleName = v.Key.StyleName, Key .Sum = v.Sum(Function(r) Double.Parse(r.Item("k001ICGeo").ToString()))})
```

I have also added a sample fiddle to show how it works with some sample data.

[**Fiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ncm67S)